# Macromolecule levels in daughter cells after fission

Tags: cell-biology, proteins, reproduction, mathematical-models, theoretical-biology

**When a prokaryote undergoes binary fission, how are the non-DNA macromolecules distributed between the two daughter cells?** This is motivated by comments on a [previous question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/2977/500) and a [G+ discussion](https://plus.google.com/u/0/101780559173703781847/posts/e7Q7eQKasC8). I am primarily interested in explicit mathematical models.

---

#### Naive model

For DNA, each copy is attached to a different part of the cell membrane, to ensure each of the daughters receives a copy. As far as I understand, there isn't such specific mechanism in place for other macromolecules. If we are allowed to assume that non-DNA macromolecules are distributed uniformly through the parent cell than this would mean the two daughter cells would receive half the proteins within statistical fluctuation. This has a specific meaning: if there are $N$ molecules of type A in the parent, then the difference in number of type A molecules in the two daughters after fission will be on the order of $\sqrt{N}$.

However, this model might be wrong. For instance, as the new cell-wall is being formed it could have in it specific pumps that either balance the protein levels below chance (producing an average difference lower than $\sqrt{N}$) or to create asymmetries higher than chance. Altenrnatively, the initial distribution of macromolecules in the parent could be far from symmetric for some other reasons. Which is the case?

**If the naive model is correct, is there experimental evidence explicitly showing this?**

Comment: [blog post discussion](http://scienceblogs.com/webeasties/2013/03/20/oas-wednesday-location-location-location/) of how the cytoplasm can't just be modeled as a homogeneous mixture.

Answer (score 2):

Many years ago I worked in the field of bacterial chemotaxis, and your question brought this paper to mind:

> JL Spudich & DE Koshland Jr. (1976) Non-genetic individuality: chance in the single cell. Nature **262**:467-471.

The authors report an analysis of the chemotactic behaviour of individual bacterial cells from a single homogeneous culture. They find marked differences between individuals, and their favoured model is what they refer to as a Poissonian variation in the inheritance of key proteins that are present in small numbers.

According to ISI Web of Science this paper has been cited 241 times - presumably at least some of those papers might be about other more recent examples of this type of phenomenon.

Comment: This is a great starting point, thank you! I will search forward from here.

Comment: Incidentally, as a counter example, there is a lot of good work showing that mRNAs are actively moved around during bud formation in yeast. This paper is probably a good place to start (in the middle of the story!).

K. A. Shepard *et al*. (2003) Widespread cytoplasmic mRNA transport in yeast: Identification of 22 bud-localized transcripts using DNA microarray analysis. Proc Natl Acad Sci U S A. **100**:11429–11434.
doi:  10.1073/pnas.2033246100