# What is the most basic organism to respond to Classical conditioning (capable of learning)?

Tags: evolution, zoology, ethology, learning

I have been doing some reading of [Classical conditioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_conditioning) which is considered to be an indication of animal's ability to learn...

Before this I considered insects to be machine like - devoid of any sort of 'thinking' just doing things that evolution 'made' them to do to survive...

However I have found that [cockroaches](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0000529) and even [fruit flies](http://www.pnas.org/content/80/5/1482.short) could be conditionally trained...

Which made me wonder **What would be the least complex species that respond to classical conditioning?**

I have also read this question about [single-celled organisms capable of learning](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/193/are-single-celled-organisms-capable-of-learning) and I don't think that this 'cuts it'... this is nothing more than chemical response... however classical conditioning is different and in my opinion certainly does indicate ability to learn...

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "first"? Earliest in evolutionary time?

Comment: @kmm Hi kmm, I am looking for the 'most basic' one, but I think that acquiring ability to learn was so advantageous that it will be same ancestor for all of us that got this ability, so evolutionary 'first' should be the same...

Comment: C. elegans, with only 302 neurons, is reportedly capable of both learning and memory, e.g. http://learnmem.cshlp.org/content/17/4/191.long so very simple nervous systems are capable of it.  Don't know how you would determine which was first in evolution, as behavior doesn't fossilize well :-)

Comment: @jamesqf Wow! Could you post it as answer please I would like to accept it... I am sure that first ancestor is long gone....

Comment: When you guys say *"the first"*, I hope you understand that the *scala naturae* is a completely wrong concept, that should be buried where it belongs: to the dark ages. I, you and a nematode worm have exactly **the same** evolutionary time, and no one (neither humans or nematodes) are *the first*.

Comment: I changed your question to ask about the least complex as opposed to the first since the "first" doesn't really mean anything (see, for example, [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/3304/1306)).

Comment: While we all have a vague intuition of what is a complex and non complex organism, the term complexity is not well defined. I would guess that the accurate definition would matter little to the purpose of the question though

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado: Actually that nematode is argually more evolved than a human (or just about any vertebrate), because evolutionary time should be measured in generations, not years.

Comment: @jamesqf Where on earth did you read that?

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado: I didn't read it.  It seems a fairly obvious conclusion from the mechanism of evolution.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado obviously, the whole idea of "more evolved" doesn't make any sense. However, if you were to use the term, the only reasonable definition for "more" or "less" evolved would be "has gone through fewer or more generations". By that measure, nematodes are indeed "more evolved" for whatever that's worth. Relevant Q&A: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/832/1306

Comment: I don't want to use an *argument from authority* here, but I will: I'm the author of a university book on evolutionary biology, and I've taught evolution for more than two decades, specially phylogenetic systematics: "more" or "less" evolved make no sense, and talking about generations makes no difference and it's not more reasonable, unless one compares a terminal with **its direct ancestors**. However, the only certain fact here is that I'm spending more time on this forum than I should... that being said, whatever you guys say is correct. Cheers.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado good grief, relax! Please read what we are saying, my comment (and my answer in the linked post) are saying precisely that the whole idea of "more" or "less" evolved is nonsensical. However, if you were to use those silly terms, the only way they might make sense is in terms of generations. And with all due respect, get off your high horse. We're all experts here and have been working for just as long as you have.

Comment: I've read what you said, and my opinion is that talking about "generations" makes absolutely no difference to the nonsensical concept of "more evolved or less evolved".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple nervous systems are capable of learning  C. elegans, with only 302 neurons, is reportedly capable of both learning and memory.  There is a fairly large literature on the subject, as C. elegans is a popular research subject - a Google Scholar search gives about 40K hits, e.g. http://learnmem.cshlp.org/content/17/4/191.long

We have to remember that small is not necessarily primitive: the C. elegans nervous system (like every other one in existence today) has been optimized by millions of generations of evolution to do what C. elegans needs in order to survive.

Actual evidence of learning in nervous systems in the distant past is rare.  It's behavior, and behavior doesn't fossilize well :-)  Actual nervous systems apparently don't fossilize all that well, either.  The earliest well-preserved example I could find was this http://www.cam.ac.uk/research/news/520-million-year-old-fossilised-nervous-system-is-most-detailed-example-yet-found from 520 million years ago.  But since learning would give a creature a survival advantage, I'd guess that it evolved fairly early.